# MeterBinders in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer

I'm trying to understand why some of the micrometer `MeterBinders` are hooked up and others not. I can see that the `MeterRegistryPostProcessor` gets all of that type from context. But why is for instance `JettyStatisticsMetrics` not in context, but `JvmGcMetrics` is?

Answer (score 0):

`MeterBinder`s need to be exposed as Spring `Bean`s in order for them to be picked up.

For Spring-Boot 1.x they need to be exposed/configured in the `micrometer-spring-legacy` project. For Spring-Boot 2 this is done in the `spring-boot` project itself.

In case you are missing some auto-configured `MeterBinder`s, don't hesitate to file an issue in the respective bug trackers: [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues) or [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/). (Please use the search. It might be these issues already have been reported.)